# Eliminating ambiguity in a grading policy

Tags: grading, syllabus

In a particular course, there will be one final exam and an online activity.

Say the final exam is worth 50 points and the online activity is worth 5 points.

Based on the following statement, how should the course be graded?

"Online activity points added to the course cumulative score."

For a sample case, we will assume a 49/50 on the exam, and 5/5 on the online activity.

While I know what the above statement means, is it ambiguous to others? If so, how can I remove the ambiguity?

EDIT1: The course grade is only made up of the final exam and online activity. There are no other sources of points.

EDIT2: I bring this up for two reasons: A student has interpreted the grading policy to mean he should get 54/50 (using the example numbers) in the course. He feels that if the points are *added* to the course cumulative score, they should not increase the total number of points possible (54/55). In order to prevent this misunderstanding in the future, I'm trying to reword the policy.

Comment: My understanding of the example you provided is the student gets 54/55. If this is not your calculation, then there is some difference between our understandings.

Comment: At least get a verb in there so the statement isn't a sentence fragment?

Comment: Good point. The existing wording of the policy was inherited, and I'm trying to clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the best way to eliminate the ambiguity is to add a concrete example to your syllabus:

> The final exam is worth 50 points and the online activity is worth 5 points. Therefore, if a student scores 48 on the final exam, and earns 4 points in the online activity, then that student will have scored 52 out of 55 points possible.

That seems much less confusing and ambiguous than:

> Online activity points [are] added to the course cumulative score

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you work with weighted averages, as being less confusing.  For example: the final exam will be worth 50% of the grade; online participation will be worth 5% of the grade.  (I just made those numbers up -- you get to figure out what your scheme is.)

Comment: I got "final exam 91%, online activity 9%" (rounded to the nearest percent).

Comment: And, of course, you will want the percentages to add up to 100%...

Comment: Yes, total must = 100%.  I was leaving out the midterm, the homeworks, the project and presentation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just edited the description above to reflect that the only graded work in the course is the final exam and online activity.

aparente001: How does working with the percentages make it less confusing? Is there something that could be misinterpreted about the original grading statement?

Comment: *Is there something that could be misinterpreted about the original grading statement?*  Yes.  //  By Nate's calculation, it sounds like you'll want something like a 90/10 split.  But I think you'll find that putting that much weight on a final exam is very hard on students, especially students who have any sort of special needs.  It sort of looks like laziness on the instructor's part (whether it is or not -- that is the appearance it gives me).

Comment: @aparente001 The points for the exam and online activity can change (i.e.: They can both have 50 points each), but I'm more interested in ensuring the grading statement is unambiguous. Does it seem though it could be misinterpreted?

Comment: *Does it seem though it could be misinterpreted?*  Yes.  *The points for the exam and online activity could vary* -- the weighting takes care of that.  Whatever percentage the student earns in his exam must by multiplied by the weight factor.